# Bytecode: LOOKUPSWITCH and TABLESWITCH

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, bcel

I am currently instrumenting bytecode using BCEL. In the BCEL API, the two instructions types `LOOKUPSWITCH` and `TABLESWITCH` (`package org.apache.bcel.generic`) are implementing interface `StackProducer`. I know that these two instructions pop the operand stack (i.e. consume it) and do not produce anything on the stack, so how come they implement `StackProducer` instead of `StackConsumer`? Is this a bug? Thank you

(ps: I tried to post this question on the BCEL mailing list with no answer. I hope I'll find more luck here)

Comment: @HH: funny, I mentionned lookupswitch and tableswitch in an answer I made today here on SO :)

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: too bad it's not related to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48908). But it has been fixed a while ago now.

```
tree:generic jbevain$ svn log -c 1081190 && svn diff -c 1081190
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1081190 | dbrosius | 2011-03-13 19:41:20 +0100 (Sun, 13 Mar 2011) | 1 line

Bug 48908 - Select instructions should implement StackConsumer instead of StackProducer
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index: Select.java
===================================================================
--- Select.java (revision 1081189)
+++ Select.java (revision 1081190)
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@
  * @see InstructionList
  */
 public abstract class Select extends BranchInstruction implements VariableLengthInstruction,
-        StackProducer {
+        StackConsumer {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 2806771744559217250L;
     protected int[] match; // matches, i.e., case 1: ...
```

`Select` is the base class for `LOOKUPSWITCH` and `TABLESWITCH`.

Comment: And here I am, fooled by the recent edit, answering a two years old question like it was freshly posted.

Comment: it's still great to know after all this time that what I suspected was right ;)